# Three js Mesh Generation - BufferAttribute.copyVector3sArray vector is undefined

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, mesh

I am building the mesh of a sphere at runtime (which will later be used for supershape generation, hence my going outside of SphereGeometry). The current vector placements seem to be working fine (tested via placing spheres at the appropriate coordinates). However, when creating the mesh from these coordinates I am encountering the error below:

```
three.min.js:532
THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector3sArray(): vector is undefined 0
copyVector3sArray   @   three.min.js:532
fromDirectGeometry  @   three.min.js:548
fromGeometry    @   three.min.js:547
setFromObject   @   three.min.js:544
get @   three.min.js:67
update  @   three.min.js:76
k   @   three.min.js:155
k   @   three.min.js:156
Wd.render   @   three.min.js:190
render  @   threedVisuals.js:520
superShapes @   threedVisuals.js:512
visualise   @   app.js:155
(anonymous) @   app.js:87
```

Using Chrome’s debugger, from what I can tell, the vertices and faces are being assigned to the mesh as expected, however, this issue gets thrown when the mesh is passed into the render cycle. The functions for this process are:

```js
function calcSphere(radius, detailLevel) {
  var globePoints = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < detailLevel; i++) { //latitude
    var lat = map_range(i, 0, detailLevel, -Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2);

    var latPoints = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < detailLevel; j++) { //longitude
      var long = map_range(j, 0, detailLevel, -Math.PI, Math.PI);

      // convert lat and long to cartesian coords
      var x = radius * Math.sin(long) * Math.cos(lat);
      var y = radius * Math.sin(long) * Math.sin(lat);
      var z = radius * Math.cos(long);

      latPoints.push({
        x,
        y,
        z
      });
    }
    globePoints.push(latPoints);
  }
  drawSphere(globePoints);
}

function drawSphere(globePoints) {

  var sphereGeo = new THREE.Geometry();

  for (var i = 0; i < globePoints.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < globePoints[i].length - 1; j++) {

      var curIndex = sphereGeo.vertices.length; //used for tracking cur location in vertices array

      var v1 = globePoints[i][j];
      sphereGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z));
      var v2 = globePoints[i + 1][j];
      sphereGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z));
      var v3 = globePoints[i][j + 1];
      sphereGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z));
      var v4 = globePoints[i + 1][j + 1];
      sphereGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(v4.x, v4.y, v4.z));


      var f1 = new THREE.Face3(
        sphereGeo.vertices[curIndex + 0],
        sphereGeo.vertices[curIndex + 1],
        sphereGeo.vertices[curIndex + 2]);
      var f2 = new THREE.Face3(
        sphereGeo.vertices[curIndex + 1],
        sphereGeo.vertices[curIndex + 2],
        sphereGeo.vertices[curIndex + 3]);

      sphereGeo.faces.push(f1);
      sphereGeo.faces.push(f2);
    }
  }

  // sphereGeo.computeFaceNormals();
  // sphereGeo.computeVertexNormals();
  var sphereMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
  var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMat);
  scene.add(sphereMesh);
}
```

Can anyone shed some light as to why this is occurring? Can’t seem to find any similar issues and relevant solves such as computing normals are also not working (`three.min.js:326 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [`THREE.Face3()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Face3) takes indices of vertices, not vertices themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @prisoner849, this was a stupid oversight.

The code block:

```
  var f1 = new THREE.Face3(
    sphereGeo.vertices[curIndex + 0],
    sphereGeo.vertices[curIndex + 1],
    sphereGeo.vertices[curIndex + 2]);
  var f2 = new THREE.Face3(
    sphereGeo.vertices[curIndex + 1],
    sphereGeo.vertices[curIndex + 2],
    sphereGeo.vertices[curIndex + 3]);
```

Should simply be:

```
        var f1 = new THREE.Face3(
          curIndex+0,
          curIndex+1,
          curIndex+2);
        var f2 = new THREE.Face3(
          curIndex+1,
          curIndex+2,
          curIndex+3);
```

No need to reference the vertices directly.